# latex code in bibtex entries

Tags: bibtex, citing

Suppose you have a mathematical paper titled

> All functions are $C^\infty$

What is the best way to deal with such a situation when citing such a title in bibtex? Does bibtex cope with mathematics in entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special to do, other than protecting the math with braces to avoid BibTeX making it lowercase.

As usual, in the example I use the `filecontents*` environment to get a self-contained document; you can normally use your `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{nice,
 author={B. C. Dull},
 title={All functions are {$C^{\infty}$}},
 journal={J. False Results},
 year={2033},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Dull proved a sensational result in~\cite{nice}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]